# Checking availability

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I'm running a book store and someone placed an order for a list of books. B,C,D,A,A,A (the parameter)
I need to return true if all of those books are found in my inventory array. If there are two instances of the same book in the list being passed in (in this case A), I need to check to see if there are that many instances of that book in my inventory. I'm traversing through both the parameter array and the inventory array but as of now my code is returning true even if there's only one A book in my inventory. I am stuck on the logic of writing code that checks to see that there are 3 A books in my inventory. In essence, the customer is placing an order and I need to tell them if I have the books he wants. The order list will be arranged in descending order of retail value. So all three A books will be right next to each other if that makes it easier. 
Here is the skeleton of what I have so far.

```
public boolean checkAvailability(customersOrder listToCheck) {
    for(int i = 0; i<listToCheck.items.length; i++){ //listToCheck's items array
        for(int j = 0; j<items.length; j++){ //inventory array
            if(listToCheck.items[i].equals(items[j])){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: You could transform the order into a mapping *title* -> *quantity*.  Then, the lookup should be really easy (and efficient).  (In your example: `{"A" : 3, "B" : 1, "C" : 1, "D" : 1}`)

Comment: I would start by grouping item and qty together. Something like `{B-> 1, A->3, C->1, D->1}`. Same for inventory.

Answer (score 0):

This is very dependent on how you are storing your data, the simplest and most generic way that will work with virtually all data designs though is:

- Sort your array before processing it, this will group all identical books together.

Now when you look to see whether you have enough books you can check there are enough to cover every instance of that book within the order.

Comment: Sorry. Missed putting in an important tidbit in the description. The inventory and the lists are ordered in descending order of retail value (which is given by .getRetailValue()). We can't use any sorting algorithm or Collections or any other features. It's supposed to be simple array manipulation.

Comment: Your example input is not sorted, it has A at the front and 2 A at the end.

Comment: My mistake. I looked over my project again and realized they would appear next to each other.

Comment: @samz_manu not entirely necessary if A and B have the same retail value.

Comment: @Joop Eggen The project is set up so that each book (A, B, C, D and so forth) have different retail values. And they are arranged in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

As this looks like homework (too simple restrictive datastructures), just an idea

```
Walk the listToCheck
    For the ith element, say A we handle all As
    If it occurs before i too, skip (you handled it already)
    Count the same items >= i: `quantity`

    Loop the stock to find `#quantity` items.
    If after the loop #quantity not reached, return failure
If after the walk of listToCheck reached
return success
```

If the same items appear one after another the quantity can be determined simply, and the loop becomes simpler.